# terminal won't pick up java

Tags: installation, java

Why does the terminal say java doesn't exist?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the output of `file /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java`?

Comment: Need whole output of `file ...`.

Comment: So +1 on the comment.  It was a 32 bit OS, but they downloaded the x64 JDK.  It pointed me in the right direction so it helped.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/java` is a symbolic link to whichever is the current system version of java. The error indicates that the link is currently pointing to a file that no longer exists. (Use `ls -al /usr/bin/java` to see which).

You need to run `sudo update-alternatives --config java` and select Oracle Java 7 as the desired version, and it should correct all the java related links for you. I would have expected the installation process for this java package to have done this, but evidently something went wrong.

Comment: see 4th screenshot

Comment: Hmm, the links do appear to be set up correctly. Do you still get a file not found error if you try and do `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java` directly in a terminal?

Comment: no such file or directory